# MySql trigger update table after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert-update

I have a Mysql trigger, I want to update column (status_id) of table "Horario" to 2, when there is an Insert into table "Consulta" (And I want to get codHorario inserted, and update status for this same code "Horario.id".

The trigger was compilled, but I noticed it is preventing my Insert command to work. When I delete the trigger, the Insert works normally.

Trigger code below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER alterar_status_horario
BEFORE INSERT
   ON consulta FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   DECLARE cod varchar(50);

   SELECT codHorario() INTO cod;

   UPDATE horario set status_id = 2 where id = cod;

END
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your `CREATE TABLE` for the two tables, the `CREATE FUNCTION` for `codHorrario()`, and your failing `INSERT` query?

Comment: In a mini test, I can't reproduce the problem. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbe11/1).